# How to delete a file owned by another user

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

As the owner of the a folder I want to use the v3 python files API to remove a file that is owned by another user. This is a recurrent topic, but I have not found a solution that fully explains the workflow.

The general assumption I am making is that I *should* be able to remove files in a folder that I own.

Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

When trying to permanently delete a file:

```
service.files().delete( fileId=file_id ).execute()
```

Results in:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1zbEBsHRpqbGkDJ6Gh5eU8OxU4IVEAo0I? returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">
```

When trying to trash the file:

```
service.files().update( fileId=file_id, body={'trashed':True} ).execute()
```

Results in:

```
ERROR: Error deleting file: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1zbEBsHRpqbGkDJ6Gh5eU8OxU4IVEAo0I?alt=json returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">
```

If I try to update the file permission to redefine the owner as myself:

```
perms = { 'emailAddress': '<myemail>@gmail.com', 'type': 'user', 'role': 'owner', 'kind': 'drive#permission' }
service.permissions().create( fileId=file_id, transferOwnership=True, body=perms ).execute()
```

Results in:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1zbEBsHRpqbGkDJ6Gh5eU8OxU4IVEAo0I/permissions?alt=json&transferOwnership=true returned "Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, you do not have permission to share."">
```

Variations of this topic have been floating around, but I haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: why would Google API allow you to delete a file that doesnt belong to you? why?

Comment: A valid question. My answer is: The parent folder belongs to me. This is not entirely unprecedented. I am permitted to delete another user's file in a linux directory whose owner uid is the same as mine (and not root user).

Answer (score 1):

> "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."

Means exactly that you do not have the permissions needed to preform the action you are trying to preform.  You can not delete a file that you do not own.   Even if the file is in a directory that you do own. This is a limitation in Google drive and has nothing to do with your code.

The solution is to get the owner of the file to delete it or to give you ownership of the file in question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I CAN delete the file (belonging to another user) from the Drive Web UI. If I am able to delete it from the WebUI, then why am I unable to use REST/python to perform the same operation?

Comment: Taking a step back, my use case is: I send out a request to one or more people to upload files to my drive. I use a cron job that runs a python script to download the files locally from the google drive. Then delete the files from my google drive. Everything up until the delete of the files works like a charm.

Comment: service account with the cron job?

Comment: I'm using an _installed app_ (OAuth and caching the token for subsequent access - works great). Are there any limitations using a _service account_? I had some trouble early on using a service account.

Comment: only that you need to remember to grant yourself access to files uploaded by the service account.   the thing is there are things you can do with the web version that you can't with the API as you have already noticed

Comment: Does using a _service account_ as you suggest require delegating domain-wide authority (i.e. G Suite required)?

Comment: Regarding: _"I CAN delete the file (belonging to another user) from the Drive Web UI."_ Keep in mind that when you "Remove" a file that is owned by someone else but shared with you as an editor, you aren't actually deleting it from that owner's drive. You're removing the "shortcut" to it, but the user could still find it in their own drive by searching for it. Upon "Removal" by a the non-owning user, the file may actually then reappear back to the owner's "My Drive" root. You can test this by uploading a large file and observing storage usage metrics are unchanged when a non-owner "Removes".